# Check if user is logged in from different domain

Tags: php, javascript, jsonp

Thanks to stackoverflow I got my little project going, but I am in need of some advice again. I would like to check if a user is logged on domain1.com and return a message on domain2. There is a lot more to the code. Below I have included a basic example of it.

index.php on http://domain2.com

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain1.com/test.php?js"></script>
```

test.php is on http://domain1.com.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['js'])){
header("Content-type:text/javascript");
?>

function doAjax(){
$.getJSON("http://domain1.com/index.php/home/callback.php?name=name&callback=?",
function(message) {
alert("Data Saved");
});
}

document.write('<button onclick="doAjax();">Submit</button>');
<?php } ?>

<?php exit; } ?>
```

callback.php is on http://domain1.com. This is where I would like to check if the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in, the file gets written, if not I want to send a message to domain2.com asking for login.

```
<?php
$callback = $_GET['callback'];

$name = $_GET['name'];

$myFile = "txt/tester.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $name);
fclose($fh);

header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
?>

<?php echo $callback; ?>("Message from the server");
```

This last part I got from a previous question. `<?php echo $callback; ?>("Message from the server");` If that's the message to domain2, how do I call it?

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, domain 2 is expecting a JSONP object from callback.php on domain 1. To format your message in a JSON object, enclose your message in an associative array (e.g: `$msg = array('message' => 'This is the callback message');`, and then pass it back to domain 2 with `echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($msg).')';` Also, set the `Content-Type` in your `header()` declaration to `application/json`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you tell me where everything goes? I've been trying but can't get it to work.